# Smoothing a density field in Python

Tags: cosmology, field-theory, computational-physics, density, software

I want to smooth a density field. It's represented as a contour plot. The data were given from a 3d array. A smoothed field should be periodic but what I take does not have periodicity. The code I use is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
central_plane = planes[:,:,64]
sigma = 1 * 10^12
data = gaussian_filter(central_plane, sigma)
plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.ylim([0, 100])
plt.contourf(data)
plt.show()
plt.xlabel("Box Size (Mpc/h)")
plt.ylabel("Box Size (Mpc/h)")
plt.colorbar(label="Density Contrast", orientation="vertical")
```

The values plotted are density values. The axes labels show the size of my simulation box. The "central_plane" is the slice of the 3d array I want to plot. The sigma I use for the smoothing corresponds to solar masses (i.e. 10^12 times the mass of the Sun for this case). Could you please help me?

[image: the initial density field]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: Probably you need to add [more color levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960480/matplotlib-colorbar-smoothness), for smoothing a picture, but yes, question is not about physics but rather about Python matplotlib library.